# java string split regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `(1, 2, 3, 4)`, and I want to parse the integers into an array.

I can use `split(",\\s")` to split all but the beginning and ending elements.  My question is how can I modify it so the beginning and ending parenthesis will be ignored?

Comment: Have you thought about looking at the substring from 1 to length-2? If you do this, then the string should be separable with split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better served by matching the numbers instead of matching the space between them. Use

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("(1, 2, 3, 4)");
while (m.find()) System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
```

Comment: The less reliable the data, the better this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 regexes: first that removes parenthesis, second that splits:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String[] elements = m.group(1).split("\\s*,\\s*");
}
```

And pay attention on my modification of your split regex. It is much more flexible and safer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use substring() and then split(",")

```
  String s = "(1,2,3,4)";
  String s1 = s.substring(1, s.length()-2);//index should be 1 to length-2
  System.out.println(s1);

  String[] ss = s1.split(",");
  for(String t : ss){
    System.out.println(t);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to use `split("[^(),\\s]")` instead.

Comment: This will create 2 extra elements: empty strings in the beginning and end.